# Shell: too many argument by '!'

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

```
n='!' && [ -n ${n} ] && echo "n=$n"
```

produces the following message

```
[: too many arguments
```

Why?

EDIT:

I'm using `zsh`

```
➔ echo $ZSH_VERSION
5.0.7
```

(with `oh-my-zsh`)

Comment: In zsh 5.0.8,  `n='!' && [ -n ${n} ] && echo "n=$n"` works fine and produces `n=!`

Comment: Upgrading to zsh 5.2 solved the problem for me.

Comment: Ah, just saw this. Not sure about if the problem is with zsh 5.0.7 or with oh-my-zsh and 5.0.7.

Comment: Works in 5.0.5 as well, so one possibility is that it was a short-lived regression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work for me fine:

```
☻  n='!' && [ -n ${n} ] && echo "n=$n"
n=!

~
☻  echo $ZSH_VERSION
5.0.8
```

(With prezto)

This might be related to the zsh version itself and hence is useful as an 'answer'.

Comment: Sorry that is not an answer. At most a comment. Besides, it does not help me find out what my problem is.

Comment: I posted this as an 'answer' since a newer version of zsh did not have this problem, before spending time figuring out what the problem is, I was hoping you could try either upgrading zsh version OR removing oh-my-zsh any any custom changes from `.zshrc`